# Find Comebacks in Football Database With Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, sql-server-2016

I have 4 tables.

**Matches**:

```
 | id    | HomeTeamID  | AwayTeamID |
 --------|-------------|------------
 | 1     | 1           | 2
 | 2     | 1           | 3
 | 3     | 3           | 1
```

**Goals**:

```
 | id    | MatchID     | Minute    | TeamID
 --------|-------------|---------- |---------
 | 1     | 1           |     3     |   2
 | 2     | 1           |     5     |   1
 | 3     | 1           |     15    |   1
 | 4     | 2           |     43    |   3
 | 5     | 2           |     75    |   1
 | 6     | 2           |     85    |   1
 | 7     | 3           |     11    |   1
 | 8     | 3           |     13    |   3
 | 9     | 3           |     77    |   3
```

**Teams**:

```
 | id    | Name        | 
 --------|-------------|
 | 1     | Chelsea     | 
 | 2     | Arsenal     | 
 | 3     | Tottenham   |
```

**Managers**:

```
 | id    | Name        | TeamID     |  
 --------|-------------|-------------
 | 1     | Conte       |    1
 | 2     | Wenger      |    2
 | 3     | Pochettino  |    3
```

I want to get the number of comebacks matches for managers. For example, Conte's team conceded the first goal in match 1 and 2 but they won. So Conte has 2 comebacks. Pochettino has 1 comeback at match 3. I want to find that with SQL Query.

I found the first goal of matches for each team. But after some steps, I'm losing what I'm doing.

```
SELECT MatchID, MIN(minute), g.TeamID
FROM Goals g
JOIN Managers m ON m.TeamID = g.TeamID
GROUP BY MatchID, g.TeamID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "Comeback" means that team conceded first goal, but team won this game.

I use 2 general subquery, 1) `winners` which contains `MatchID` and `TeamID`  from each game which not ended as draw. And 2) `first_goals`, which  contains those `TeamID`'s, which scored first goal in match.

So, joining between these subqueries using:

`on winners.MatchID = first_goals.MatchID and winners.TeamID <> first_goals.TeamID`

gives us those matchs, where team won, but not scored first goal (i.e "Comeback").

Finally we use simple joins  with `Teams` and `Managers` tables:

```
with Goals(id    , MatchID    , Minute   ,TeamID)   as (
    select 1     , 1           ,     3     ,   2 union all
    select  2     , 1           ,     5     ,   1 union all
    select  3     , 1           ,     15    ,   1 union all
    select 4     , 2           ,     43    ,   3 union all
    select  5     , 2           ,    75    ,   1 union all
    select 6     , 2           ,     85    ,   1 union all
    select  7     , 3           ,     11    ,   1 union all
    select  8     , 3           ,     13    ,   3 union all
    select 9     , 3           ,     77    ,   3 
),
Teams (id, Name) as(
    select 1     ,'Chelsea' union all
    select  2     ,'Arsenal' union all
    select  3     ,'Tottenham'  
),
Managers(id, Name, TeamID) as (
select  1    ,'Conte',    1 union all
select  2     ,'Wenger',   2 union all
select  3     ,'Pochettino',    3
 )

select winners.TeamID, winners.MatchID, Teams.Name, Managers.Name from  ( 
    select t1.* from 
    (
        select TeamID, MatchID, count(*) as goal_scored  from Goals
        group by TeamID, MatchID 
    )t1
    inner join 
    (
        select MatchID, max(goal_scored) as winner_goals_cnt from (
            select TeamID, MatchID, count(*) as goal_scored  from Goals
            group by TeamID, MatchID
        )t
        group by MatchID
        having min(goal_scored) <> max(goal_scored)
    )t2
    on t1.MatchID = t2.MatchID and t1.goal_scored = t2.winner_goals_cnt
) winners
inner join 
(
    select * from (
    select Goals.*, row_number() over(partition by MatchID order by  Minute, id) rn from Goals
    ) f
    where rn = 1
) first_goals
on winners.MatchID = first_goals.MatchID and winners.TeamID <> first_goals.TeamID
inner join Teams
on winners.TeamID = Teams.id
inner join Managers
on winners.TeamID = Managers.TeamID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte 
(
MatchID,TeamID,TotalGoalTime,NoOfGoals,ManagerName,comeback)
as(SELECT MatchID, g.TeamID,sum(minutea) as'TotalGoalTime' ,count(*)as'NoOfGoals',m.name as'ManagerName'
,comeback =ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MatchID order by sum(minutea) desc) 
FROM Goals g
JOIN Managers m ON m.TeamID = g.TeamID
join [Teams] t on t.Id=g.TeamId
GROUP BY MatchID, g.TeamID,m.name )
Select MatchID,TeamID,NoOfGoals,ManagerName from cte where comeback =1
```

The above query for now gives us the overall comeback, Will update the no of come backs.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to count every comeback in football match, you can use the solution below. Then the definition of the comeback is every time when a team score one goal more the opponent, after loosing. For example, for the following scenario we have three comebacks:

```
Team A  Team B
  0    -   1     //team b scores
  1    -   1     //team a scores
  2    -   1     //team a scores (comeback for a)
  2    -   2     //team b scores 
  2    -   3     //team b scores (comeback for b)
  3    -   3     //team a scores
  4    -   3     //team a scores (comeback for a)
```

From the above it seems that we have a comeback, when score is changed, and the previous score was even. I am using [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) with [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) and `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` ordering by `minute` in order to calculated the score each time a goal is scored.

Here is full working example:

```
DECLARE @matches TABLE
(   
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[HomeTeamID] TINYINT
   ,[AwayTeamID] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @Goals TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[MatchID] TINYINT
   ,[Minute] TINYINT
   ,[TeamID] TINYINT
);

DECLARE @Teams TABLE
(
    [id] TINYINT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
);

DECLARE @Managers TABLE
(
    [Id] TINYINT
   ,[Name] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[TeamID] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @matches ([id], [HomeTeamID], [AwayTeamID])
VALUES (1, 1, 2)
      ,(2, 1, 3)
      ,(3, 3, 1)
      ,(4, 1, 4);

INSERT INTO @Goals ([id], [MatchID], [Minute], [TeamID])
VALUES (1, 1, 3, 2)
      ,(2, 1, 5, 1)
      ,(3, 1, 15, 1)
      ,(4, 2, 43, 3)
      ,(5, 2, 75, 1)
      ,(6, 2, 85, 1)
      ,(7, 3, 11, 1)
      ,(8, 3, 13, 3)
      ,(9, 3, 77, 3)
      ,(10, 4, 3, 1)
      ,(11, 4, 5, 4)
      ,(12, 4, 10, 4)
      ,(13, 4, 12, 1)
      ,(14, 4, 25, 1)
      ,(15, 4, 46, 4)
      ,(16, 4, 60, 4)
      ,(17, 4, 72, 4)
      ,(18, 4, 84, 4);

INSERT INTO @Teams ([id], [Name])
VALUES (1, 'Chelsea')
      ,(2, 'Arsenal')
      ,(3, 'Tottenham')
      ,(4, 'Real Madrid');

INSERT INTO @Managers ([Id], [Name], [TeamID])
VALUES (1, 'Conte', 1)
      ,(2, 'Wenger', 2)
      ,(3, 'Pochettino', 3)
      ,(4, 'Zidane', 4);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT m.[id]
          ,m.[HomeTeamID]
          ,m.[AwayTeamID]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.[id] ORDER BY g.[minute]) AS [EventID]
          ,IIF
           (
                SUM(IIF(m.[HomeTeamID] = g.[teamID], 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.[id] ORDER BY g.[minute] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 1
                =
                SUM(IIF(m.[AwayTeamID] = g.[teamID], 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.[id] ORDER BY g.[minute] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
                OR
                SUM(IIF(m.[HomeTeamID] = g.[teamID], 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.[id] ORDER BY g.[minute] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
                =
                SUM(IIF(m.[AwayTeamID] = g.[teamID], 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY m.[id] ORDER BY g.[minute] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -1
               ,IIF(m.[HomeTeamID] = g.[teamID], 'H', 'A') -- (H)ome come back, (A)way come ba
              ,'N' -- no come back
           ) AS [ComeBack]
    FROM @matches m
    INNER JOIN @Goals g
        ON m.[id] = g.[MatchID]
)
SELECT T.[Name]
FROM DataSource DS
INNER JOIN @Teams T
    ON IIF([ComeBack] = 'H', [HomeTeamID], [AwayTeamID]) = T.[id]
WHERE DS.[EventID] <> 1
    AND DS.[ComeBack] <> 'N';
```

The above will give us:

```
Chelsea
Chelsea
Chelsea
Tottenham
Real Madrid
Real Madrid
```

Note, I have added one more match to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow much of football, but assuming that a comeback is when a team concedes the first goal but then wins the game, I would use the following logic to get the result.

First, we need the teams that had conceded the first goal in a match:

```
SELECT TeamID, MatchID FROM Goals WHERE GoalID in 
  (SELECT Min(GoalID) FROM Goals GROUP BY MatchID)
```

Second, for each match, we need the matches where the team making first goal went on to win.

```
SELECT MatchID FROM
(SELECT COUNT(GoalID) as TotalGoals, MatchID FROM Goals GROUP BY MatchID) AS MatchSummary
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(GoalID) as TeamGoals, MatchID FROM 
  (SELECT TeamID, MatchID FROM Goals WHERE GoalID in 
      (SELECT Min(GoalID) FROM Goals GROUP BY MatchID)
  ) as GoalsOfTheTeamThatConcededFirstGoal 
GROUP BY MatchID) as SummaryOfTeamThatConcededFirstGoal
ON MatchSummary.MatchID = SummaryOfTeamThatConcededFirstGoal.MatchID 
WHERE (TotalGoals - TeamGoals) < TeamGoals
```

Combining these two queries you will be able to get the TeamIDs for those teams that have made a comeback.

I think this task could be done much better with cursors or temporary tables, but I wanted to keep the answer as simple as possible. Hence I have avoided it. You should definitely explore those two methods.